# How to make a dictionary from text file using First row as the key

Tags: python, text, key-value, csv

I'm trying to do COVID monitoring from a text file to a dictionary to check every country's cases.
I want to make a dictionary in this format.

```
covid ={country{confirmed:value, active:value, recovered:value, suspect:value, probable:value, 
deceased:value}
```

Based on this text file.

```
 COUNTRY, CONFIRMED, ACTIVE, RECOVERED, SUSPECT, PROBABLE, DECEASED
 COUNTRY-A,3,4,2,1,0,0
 COUNTRY-B,1,2,0,2,0,0
 COUNTRY-C,4,2,0,0,3,0
 COUNTRY-D,1,1,1,3,0,0
 COUNTRY-E,3,2,0,2,0,0
 COUNTRY-F,2,0,1,2,0,0
 COUNTRY-G,0,0,1,4,0,0
```

I tried this code but it prints the COUNTRY, CONFIRMED, ACTIVE, RECOVERED, SUSPECT, PROBABLE, DECEASED
and it gives me an error every time I compute the total number of cases in each country.

I tried this code:

```
def covid_monitoring():
country = []
cov_dict = {}
no_cases = []
with open("covidmonitor.txt", 'r') as f:

    for cov in f:
        cov = cov.strip()
        next(f)  # skip header
        if len(cov) >= 1:
            cov_line = cov.split(",")
            country.append(cov_line[0].strip())
            confirmed_file = cov_line[0].strip()
            active_file = cov_line[1].strip()
            recovered_file = cov_line[2].rstrip()
            suspected_file = cov_line[3].strip()
            probable_file = cov_line[4].strip()
            probable_file = cov_line[5].strip()
            deceased_file = cov_line[6].strip(';')
            if confirmed_file not in cov_dict:
                cov_dict[confirmed_file] = [(active_file,  recovered_file, suspected_file, probable_file, probable_file, deceased_file)]
            else:
                cov_dict[confirmed_file].append((active_file, recovered_file, suspected_file, probable_file, probable_file, deceased_file))
   # print(cov_dict)
for cntry in country:
    if cntry in cov_dict:
        for confirm, active, recovered, suspect, probable, deceased in cov_dict[cntry]:
            print("\tCOUNTRY:{cntry}")
            print("\tCONFIRMED:{confirm} ")
            print("\tACTIVE:{active} ")
            print("\tRECOVERED:{recovered} ")
            print("\tSUSPECTED:{suspect} ")
            print("\tPROPBABLE:{probable} ")
            print("\tDECEASED:{deceased} ")
            total_count = int(confirm) + int(active) + int(recovered) + int(suspect) + int(probable) + int(deceased)
            
            no_cases.apped(total_count)
            print(sum(no_cases)
```

This is my error:

```
     total_count = int(confirm) + int(active) + int(recovered) + int(suspect) + int(probable) + int(deceased)
     ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'CONFIRMED'
```

Comment: As a comment on question quality: please try to always include the exact error message in the question to make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to skip header, don't call next on every loop.

```py
with open("covidmonitor.txt", 'r') as f:
    # f.readlines()[1:] read all line except first line
    for cov in f.readlines()[1:]:
        cov = cov.strip()
```

It seems like it is a csv file. You also can use csv package in python like this.

```py
import csv

no_cases= []
country= []
cov_dict = {}
with open("covidmonitor.txt", 'r') as f:
    cov = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",", skipinitialspace=True)
    for country_data in cov:
        total_count = [float(data) for key, data in c.items() if key != 'COUNTRY']
        no_cases.append(sum(total_count))
        country.append(country_data['COUNTRY'])
        cov_dict[country_data['COUNTRY']] = total_count
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code, `no_cases` is a list of strings, because `confirm`, `active`, `recovered`, `suspect`, `probable`, `deceased` are all strings and

```
total_count= (confirm + active + recovered + suspect + probable + deceased)
```

is also a string, which is the concatenation rather than the sum.

Calling `sum()` on a list of strings at hte last line of your code should produce an error like this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

You should convert all of these to integers if you want to treat them as numbers.

---

There are other problems with your code, too. For example, you call `next(f)` to skip the header, but you actually do it inside the `for` loop over lines in the file, so it is probably skipping every other line.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to convert to int. I will edit it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python pandas package for this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("COVID19.TXT", sep=",")
covid = data.set_index("COUNTRY").T.to_dict()
print(covid)
```

Also, a suggestion for analytics you can compute various functions on pandas dataframe easily and then convert to dict if required. Check this link here for more details: [Pandas tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-python-tutorial/)

Let me know in the comments if you need more help.